# Strange Error - Please help understand this

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, xml

I am trying to write a direct query in Magento and it is working fine in my local but in the test environment it is giving the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 36: parser error : expected '&gt;' in /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510' in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:245
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'simplexml_load_...', '/var/www/html/l...', 510, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php(510): simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="...', 'Mage_Core_Model...')
#2 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php(498): Varien_Simplexml_Config->loadString('<?xml version="...', 'Mage_Core_Model...')
#3 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(277): Varien_Simplexml_Config->loadFile('/var/www/html/a...')
#4 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(380): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadBase()
#5 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(268): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initBaseConfig()
#6 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(616): Mage_Core_Model_App->init('', 'store', Array)
#7 / in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 245
```

I have not touched Magento core files.

Comment: Its seems your configuration having issue, debug your configuration like mentioned in -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835275/how-do-i-know-whether-my-config-xml-file-is-working-in-magento#7836535

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *sql does not create issue this issue*.`Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: simplexml_load_string()` issue  is created for xml.

***There are some issue in your layout files or config.xml,adminhtml.xml etc. You need to fix that***.

Answer (score 1):

The `&gt;` means `>`

So you are missing a closing `>` in some xml configuration on line 36 if I get the message right.

Did you change some configuration files lately? You should start there. If not, you could add some temporary debug code in https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php#L495 to get the filename of the broken xml file

Answer (score 0):

1. Please disable All third party extension, and then check the issue
2. If issue is resolved please enable third party extension one by one
   and check the issue.
3. If disabling third party extension not help please use the new setup files for this